# Displaying a PNG file over a OpenLayers v6 map

Tags: openlayers

I am having difficulty finding a clear solution to this, I may just be over complicating it but I am not sure how to just add a static PNG file over top of a OpenLayers map with a opacity of 0.5. I've been searching the documentation and other related question but none have seemed to clear things up.

Could someone point me in the right direction, the data bounds are N: 85.044, S: -85.044, E: 180, W: -180. The image is of SMAP (Soil Moisture Active Passive) data I have processed with Python and exported as a PNG to display over this map in OpenLayers. Would leaving it as girdded data (simply stored in a matrix) make it easier/simpler to project?

This is  my image to add to the mapand it's size is 3856x1624. I know the black of the image will make it hard to see teh rest of the map, however right now I am just trying to get an image to overlay on the map.

[image: SMAP data image I am trying to overlay]

Below is my most recent attempt to get it too work:

```
// Create the map object
const map = new Map({
target: 'map',
layers: [
new TileLayer({
  source: new OSM
  })  
],
view: new View({
  projection: 'EPSG:4326',
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 0
  })
});

// Extent of the SMAP data bounds 
imageextent = [-180, -85.044, 180, 85.044];

// Creating a new image layer using my PNG image as a static source
var image_layer = new ImageLayer({
  source: new Static({
    url: 'dataImage.png',
    imageExtent: imageextent,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    crossOrigin: ''
  }),
  className: 'Image_Layer',
  opacity: 0.5,
  extent: imageextent,
  map: map  // This should add the image as an overlay
})
```

So when I run this using Node.js I have a map in EPSG:4326, but no image on top.

Comment: One of the basic policies of this side requires that coding questions should include relevant part of existing code of what has been tried so far, otherwise question is most likely to be closed as not being conformant to the site policy.

Comment: What is the PNG size in pixels and what projection is it in?

Comment: Apologies, I will edit it and add in all relevant information of previous attempts!

PNG size in pixels is 3856x1624 and in EPSG4326 projection.

Comment: Any errors in the debugger or network console? For me it works perfectly OK (took your .jpg picture from above), except that projection in image does not match OSM EPSG:4326 projection.

Comment: No errors whatsoever. Ah I'll have to look into the projection then, I must be mistaken

Comment: It works with a Gall-Peters projection https://codesandbox.io/s/epsg-4326-q7hy0